# Thymeleaf pass Set of Object as member of object to controller

Tags: model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got a form:

```xml
<form action="#" th:action="@{/private/createUser}" th:object="${toCreate}" method="post">

<label for="alias">User Alias</label>
<input id="alias" type="text" th:field="*{alias}"/>

<label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
<input id="fullName" type="text" th:field="*{fullName}"/>

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" th:field="*{password}"/>

<ul for="userRoles">
  <li th:each="role, roleStat : ${availableRoles}">
    <div>
      <label th:for="${roleStat.count}" th:text="${role.name}">Role Name</label>
      <input th:id="${roleStat.count}" type="checkbox" th:value="${role}"/>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button type="submit" th:text="Submit" name="submitButton"></button>

</form>
```

That's supposed to provide a User object to my controller:

```java
@Controller
public class UserCreationController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/private/createUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createUser(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("availableRoles", UserRole.values());

        m.addAttribute("toCreate", new User());

        return "createUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/private/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUserPost(@ModelAttribute("toCreate") User toCreate, Model m, HttpServletResponse response) {
        FlexibleResponse resp = userService.createUser(toCreate);
        if (resp.isPositive()) {
            m.addAttribute("success", resp.getContent());
        } else {
            m.addAttribute("failure", resp.getContent());
        }

        response.setStatus(resp.isPositive() ? 200 : HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return "redirect:createUser";
    }
}
```

Everything works smoothly except for the "userRoles", which is a `Set<UserRole> userRoles;` UserRole is an enum (you can probably tell by looking at the controller). What do I need to do in order to bind these checkboxes as a Set inside my `th:object="${toCreate}"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `th:field` for the role checkbox input. Without it, the required `name` attribute is not generated. Try this:

```xml
<label th:for="${#ids.next('userRoles')}" th:text="${role.name}">Role Name</label>
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{userRoles}" th:value="${role}"/>
```

Reference: [Checkbox fields](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#checkbox-fields) section in Thymeleaf tutorial.